# Difference between MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr) and Marshal.PtrToStringUni()

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, dllimport, extern

I would like to import a function like this:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
[DllImport("DLL.dll", EntryPoint="FuncUtf16", ExactSpelling=true, PreserveSig=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern string Func();
```

But this gives me an error like this:

"Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Test.exe. This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Test.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded. "

And when I press "Continue" repeatedly, the function does give the expected output. However, when I chance the above declaration to:

```
[DllImport("DLL.dll", EntryPoint="FuncUtf16", ExactSpelling=true, PreserveSig=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr Func();
```

(changing the return type to IntPtr) and call it as follows:

```
Dim a As IntPtr = Func()
Dim Str As String = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni(a)
```

, I get no errors and it works perfectly fine! Whats wrong with using the "MarshalAs" way of declaring a function in a dll?

Comment: You'd better write a little test program and call that function a billion times.  Pretty likely that it is going to reveal a memory leak.  The leak that the marshaller tried to prevent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing the PInvoke signature for a method which returns a `char* / wchar_t*` requires a lot of care because the CLR special cases `string` return types.  It makes the following assumptions

- The memory for the `char*` must be freed after converting to `string`
- The memory was allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc`

If either of these aren't true (usually the case) then the program will run into errors.

In general it's best to simply return an `IntPtr` and manually marshal the string as you've done with `PtrToStringUni`.

Comment: Thanks very much! I just don't understand one thing: marshalling a returned IntPtr doesn't free the memory for the char* right? So the error I get is because of the second point you gave: that it wasnt allocated with CoTaskMemAlloc? Right?

Comment: @user815305 correct. You still need to free the memory after you use `PtrToStringUni`

Comment: But if I do "Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(a)" afterwards, I get the same error as I get when I use the PInvoke signature way: heap corruption. Is it ok to leave it unfreed?

Comment: @user815305 it depends on how the memory is allocated and whether or not the callee is responsible for freeing the memory.  hard to say without seeing ho the string is created in native code

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! You helped me very good, I understand it now. Thank you!